# Magento 2.2.6 installation error in Docker

Tags: magento2

I am facing this error when trying to install magento 2.2.6.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Deprecated Functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in /var/www/html/m226/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 81 in /var/www/html/m226/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'The each() func...', '/var/www/html/m...', 81, Array) #1 /var/www/html/m226/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(81): each(Array) #2 /var/www/html/m226/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 /var/www/html/m226/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 /var/www/html/m226/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, Array, true, true, true) #5 /var/www/html/m226/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Fron in /var/www/html/m226/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: what php version your system has? please refer this [system-requirement](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Comment: Yes it was a issue of system requirement. I am using php 7.2 and trying to install magento 2.2.6

Comment: Do changing the php version doesn't solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

The each() function is deprecated in php 7.2 so change this function to foreach() on line no 81.

Change

```
 while (list($name, $value) = each($options)) {
        $this->setOption($name, $value);
    }
```

To

```
foreach ($options as $name => $value){
        $this->setOption($name, $value);
    }
```

And compile the code using `php bin/magento s:d:c`
I hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: No it didnt work. and are we supposed to change file from vendor?

Comment: @sugar Yes Can you please change and check it? Also, try command php bin/magento s:d:c

Comment: Nope still no progress

Comment: Are you made changes in vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php line no 81? because it is working fine in my setup. Can you please do this below commnd php bin/magento s:up and php bin/magento s:d:c and clear cache.

Comment: Also, Please install magento 2.3.0 which is support PHP 7.2 version

Answer (score 0):

Magento **2.2** is not fully compatible with **php 7.2**
use magento **2.3** which is fully support **7.2**